# How are discontinuities in quadrature modulated signal QAM physically produced?

Tags: antenna, signal, modulation, amplitude, quadrature

In quadrature modulated signals, for instance:

[image]

I am unclear how the "discontinuities" in the waveform at the junction of each data point can be physically produced?

Taking a speaker as an example, how is it possible to produce this "discontinuity" in the sound wave by using the speaker cone's mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram just shows an ideal jump between four different sine waves. An actual signal can't change instantly and thus has a bandwidth limit how fast it can change.

But you can still digitally try to generate the ideal samples for playback, it will just be limited by sampling rate and bandwidth.

Comment: thank you, that clears things up for me! May I ask how reliable are the timing intervals in signal electronics? In software, one is resigned to the fact that setInterval(20ms) means it will return anywhere from 10-30ms, or worse... In electronics, can we be certain about the exact point in time where each symbol changes occur, or do we need to do some averaging/guessing due to time drift/lapse in the electronics processing stack?

Comment: I don't know what setinterval() is and what it does but you can make an electronic product with atomic clock precision and accuracy if you need to and run software on it at same accuracy and precision. There's no answer to that really. Usually products are as accurate as needed by some specification and I don't know what you expect from the timing. If you make a program to generate that signal as an audio file and play it on your sound card, you can be sure that sampling rate is not too far off, few tens of PPM maybe.

Comment: thank you. The thought was about how to decode analog QAM wave signal back to digital. If we can make sure (by whatever means) the precise enough cutoff points for each signal symbol, could we not then pass this through 4parallel channels each chanting out a different symbol pattern for 00, 01, 10, 11... and pick the highest amplified output as the decoded "answer" to this particular wave slice?

Comment: What you’ve shown is a PSK (phase shift keying) signal. QAM adds amplitude to the equation. To decode PSK you regenerate a reference sinewave using a phase locked loop technique. Compare the reference with the incoming signal to recover the phase. For the amplitude you get the average peak value and you can determine the relative amplitude from that. Once you have phase and amplitude you can classify the constellation points and recover the bit stream. Note there is a synch sequence in the transmitted data to allow you determine the start of the sequence.

Comment: You might want to research software modems for some hints. The open source voip package ‘Asterisk’ has some examples. Hardware timing is quite precise otherwise just about everything we rely on simply wouldn’t work.

Comment: @Kartman That's technically correct that it is PSK, but on the other hand, it's not wrong as PSK can be seen as one special case of QAM.

Comment: thank you all, it's been a lot of help to hear your answers.